# Should we make No-Front-End Wolfram Language questions explicitly on-topic? Are they?

Tags: discussion, policy

On the [Help center](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help) > [Asking](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/asking) > [What topics can I ask about here?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) one can read

> *Mathematica Stack Exchange* is for users of the software *Mathematica*
> developed by *Wolfram Research*, as well as related products like
> *gridMathematica*, *Wolfram Workbench*, *Player* (Pro), and the *CDF Player*.
> If you have a question about the Mathematica system or wish to solve a
> problem using Mathematica, then you have come to the right place!

That doesn't explicitly include [Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) or [WolframScript](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), and now that I have been working without a Front-End, it feels that many answers about *Mathematica* normally assume a Front-End will be available in many answers.

I'm assuming here that questions which explicitly require to work without a front-end are still *on-topic*, but please do comment on that if you disagree.

**Should we make No-Front-End *Wolfram Language* questions like *Wolfram Engine* or *WolframScript* explicitly on-topic?**

Comment: This may be stretching the question a bit, so I post it as a comment: should *Wolfram Engine* in *Jupyter Notebooks*, or *Visual Studio Code* also be included explicitly?

Comment: I think interacting directly with the *Mathematica* kernel is always on topic, even if you refer to the kernel by some other name.

Comment: I agree with Jason, I consider these obviously on-topic, without having to make a special statement on them.

Comment: @JasonB., I agree that should be the case, still *"it feels that many answers about Mathematica normally assume a Front-End will be available"*.

Comment: Question [Q2705](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2705/10397) is relevant here too. In practice, just interacting with the Wolfram Kernel has not always implied to be *on-topic*.