# Are questions about calling Mathematica in other languages/softwares on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Recently I voted to close [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/274730/1871) because it's about programming in python and I think it's clearly off-topic in this site. But OP of the question just showed me something funny: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10276834/1551513), which looks on-topic for stackoverlow in my view, is closed there, and according to [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10276834/timeline), the moderator there is trying to push the question to this site, and then be rejected. Following the link in the post, I then found [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4643/1871), which is off-topic in my view, remaining opened and get 70 upvotes.

So, I'd like to ask, are questions about calling *Mathematica*/Wolfram language in C/Java/python/julia/Origin/whatever on-topic in this site?

Comment: Comments in [Q2701](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2701/10397) suggest that any interaction with the Wolfram Kernel is *on-topic*, however, I agree that this need further discussion and better definition of the edge cases. That includes spelling out the status of *"Mathematica Solutions"* that just call *Java* to get a solution there as well as the case the OP mentions. One possible argument here is that a question which requires knowledge of two or more programming languages is better placed in a site with broader scope (StackOverlow) and not one that specializes in one of them.

Comment: Generally, I'd say that that such questions are still on-topic. However, there have been individual questions that have more specific characteristics that make them off-topic or just bad questions. E.g. if being able to answer the question requires detailed knowledge of some non-MMA language or library, or if the question goes beyond the MMA link question and into how to write the code in the other language.

Comment: Probably *"being able to answer the question requires detailed knowledge of some non-MMA language"* should not  imply that questions are meant adjust to the programming level of the people. Questions should fit the agreed scope of the site. Very likely we do have enough people fluent in other languages, but the scope of this site is not *general programming in all languages*, but it is (so far) focused and specialized in a single one. That said, I wouldn't oppose broadening the scope, provided we agree on a new scope that makes sense.